# How to disable -Wvexing-parse for one line in clang?

Tags: c++, clang++

Clang enables [`-Wvexing-parse`](https://releases.llvm.org/11.0.0/tools/clang/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wvexing-parse) by default, which is a good thing.

Sometimes, however, I would like to *declare* a function (`f()`) within a scope of another function (`g()`) as `g()` is the only function that needs to be aware of `f()`.

Is there a way to tell clang "I do mean to declare a function" via a comment on a particular line?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

// header file
int g()
{
    const char *f(); //HOW TO clang-disable-vexing-parse?
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;    
}

// cpp file
const char *f()
{
    return "";
}

// main.cpp
int main()
{
    g();
}
```

([Online example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/841c12bd4dbfe302)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wvexing-parse"

const char *f(); 

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
std::cout << f() << std::endl;
```

Should do what you want.

But it's actually not necessary to disable the warning if you declare your function `f()` *properly* as a function that takes no arguments (thus `f(void)`) and should achieve the same thing.

```
#include <iostream>

// header file
int g(void)
{
    const char *f(void); //HOW TO clang-disable-vexing-parse?
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;    
}

// cpp file
const char *f(void)
{
   return "";
}

// main.cpp
int main()
{
   g();
}
```

Comment: The parameter lists `(void)` and `()` are equivalent in C++ (but not in C).

Comment: @molbdnilo Well, we could say that there's *one* difference: one is unambiguous to the tools, the other triggers a warning in this corner case.